# I need a way to retrieve and log the IMEI, Serial, ICCID, and MEID of an iPhone device connected via usb

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, serial-number, imei

As it says in the title I'm after a way to retrieve and log the IMEI, Serial, ICCID, and MEID of an iPhone device connected via usb.

Ideally this method would work with multiple devices plugged in at once and export the information to a spreadsheet with the information separated by column.

Trying to develop a better inventory system for my company's iPhone fleet.

I've been struggling with this for a while now to no avail.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` from a shell to list the USB information, including the serial number of an attached iPhone - you could parse this.

> USB Hi-Speed Bus:

```
  Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBEHCI
  PCI Device ID: 0x0aa6 
  PCI Revision ID: 0x00b1 
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x10de 
  Bus Number: 0x24 

    iPhone:

      Product ID: 0x12a8
      Vendor ID: 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
      Version:  6.02
      Serial Number: 797296a8472XXXXXXXXXf5806511452228ac9
      Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
      Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
      Location ID: 0x24300000 / 3
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 500
      Extra Operating Current (mA): 500
```

To get things like the IMEI you will need to communicate with the actual phone, probably using [IOUSBLib](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002645-BBIHCIHB) and you will need to do a lot of research on the USB primitives supported by the iPhone as I don't know how well documented they are.

It is probably easier to use a commercial Mobile Device Management (MDM) platform.